# How do I pass multiple values to the command line?

Tags: drush

My module will be run from the command line.  The Drush command would be something like this:

```
drush create-denver-type --name="some title" --title="some title" --options="apple" --userid="myid"
```

`--options` can have one option or five. I'm using a `switch` statement and only passing one value through `--options`. What do I need to do to pass two or three values to `--options`, for example `--options="apple, pear, orange"`?

Basing on the values passed in `--options`, different functions will be called.

When gathering multiple values, how do I pass them to my function, and call the correct functions based on the value passed in `--options`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$options = drush_get_option_list('options');
```

This will return something like `array('apple')` or `array('apple','pear','orange')`.

Yeah, Drush does everything.

Comment: I don't know how to incorporate a foreach into the code so that it will determine what values are in the array and then run the needed function(s). I made an edit above to show show where I am stuck in my switch.

Comment: Now THAT question is out of scope for Drupal Stack Exchange. You could use a foreach / switch, or perhaps call_user_func to do what you'd like, but basic php questions should be asked elsewhere.

Comment: Where is drush_get_option_list implemented ? Is it a certain drush version ? I think that does not answer how to implement a drush command with a dynamic amount of options. Eg think of a command to check for access for a certain route and you want to give the route paramters which depends on how much parameters the route accepts.